# How to create a new alias in Windows Powershell for deleting multiple folders?

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, alias

I want to create an alias in Windows PowerShell to delete multiple folders from the command line.

To remove more than one item I call:

`Remove-Item '.\Documents\*\Bin\' ,'.\Documents\*\Inter\' -Force -Recurse`

I have tried to create the alias like this:

`New-Alias -Name 'Clean-RCD' Remove-Item '.\Documents\*\Bin\' ,'.\Documents\*\Inter\' -Force -Recurse`

Output:
`New-Alias: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.`

Any idea how to define this alias correctly?

Comment: `New-Alias` is meant for cmdlets or functions loaded on your session. i.e.: `New-Alias -Name rm -Value Remove-Item`. Note that `rm` is already an alias for `Remove-Item`: `Get-Alias rm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in bash, aliases in PowerShell are strict 1-to-1 command name mappings - no extra parameter arguments allowed.

You'll want to create a `function` instead:

```
function Clean-RCD {
  Remove-Item -Path '~\Documents\*\Bin', '~\Documents\*\Inter\' -Force -Recurse
}
```

Use of `~` (which resolves to your home folder) over `.` is intentional - this way it'll still work if you've navigated to a different path

Comment: When I call the function I still need to specify the path :

```cmdlet Remove-Item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]:
Remove-Item: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty array.```

Comment: Remember to remove any alias with the same name you might have created earlier (`Remove-Alias Clean-RCD`) - aliases take precedence over function names when PowerShell resolves commands by name